# Retrieving string columns from a MySQL resultset

Tags: c++, mysql

My initial code:

```
std::string query = "SELECT login,passw FROM people WHERE login = '" + slovo + "'";
const char* q = query.c_str();
qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
res = mysql_store_result(conn);
```

I need to use the data (login, password) to get a string in the database. If the string exists, then.... otherwise....
Tell me how to get a string for 2 variables and how to write a condition.

Comment: Avoid to construct SQL query by string concatenation, use binding variables instead. (See [Exploits of Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Comment: While it doesn't seem to me that the duplicate is correct (OP is not asking about prepared statements!), I do not understand what OP is asking about :)